# Deleted Partition Recovery

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

I was installing ubuntu 12.04 on my system. There were 4 partitions on my system and I selected one of the four partition for the installation and chose the option of resizing the partition. Initially my partition was of size 100+GB and i created another partition out of it of size 15GB (EXT4). Now the moment I changed this partition structure my original partition got lost along with its data and I am left with 50GB partition and 50GB unallocated free space.

Now the data that I have lost is meant a lot to me and I want to recover that data. So is there any way I can recover it? And I haven't checked "format" option while resizing the partition.

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery and further info by the author of Testdisc, Christoffe Grenier: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step not to mention the ubuntu *manpage* for testdisk

Comment: For the sake of completion, there's also [an old thread at the Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121) explaining how to recover deleted partitions using *gpart*.

Comment: thanks for all the hints. I've had a similar issue and the above mentioned Testdisk utility did a great job for me, recovering exactly the state as it was before erasing the partition, thus I have lost no data. More precisely, I have: 1. booted from the Ubuntu-Rescue-Remix DVD (mentioned above) into live mode 2. used the testdisk utility (available right away, no need for internet connection and/or apt-get install testdisk).
I have followed the steps from http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 6):

> Warning: If you follow these instructions you **must** install testdisk on a *different* Ubuntu system than the one you're trying to recover (for example, you could install it in a live environment, or you could put the hard disk into another computer that has Ubuntu on it). If you install anything on a disk from which you wish to recover data, or save anything to it, it becomes far harder to recover anything because more data are overwritten.

You can try testdisk to recover it. I hope you can recover it, because you didn't formatted the space it. Only the partition table is changed.

Install it via Software center [testdisk [image: Install testdisk]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk)

or by using `sudo apt-get install testdisk` command in the terminal.

Then run it with sudo command, i.e `sudo testdisk`. Please Don't forget to read the manual of it. [manpage for the `testdisk` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/testdisk)

Comment: Just one question - if you restore a partition incorrectly, does that overwrite the partition that you actually wanted to recover?

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Yes, It can

Comment: I had a terrible experience with testdisk. I'm using gdisk in future.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ubuntu-Rescue-Remix

> Ubuntu-Rescue-Remix provides a robust yet lean system for data
>   recovery and forensics. No graphical interface is used; the live
>   system can boot and function normally on machines with very little
>   memory or processor power. Following Ubuntu's six-month release
>   schedule, all the software is up-to-date, stable and supported.
>
> Ubuntu-Rescue-Remix features a full command-line environment with the
>   newest versions of the most powerful free/libre open-source data
>   recovery software including GNU ddrescue, Photorec, The Sleuth Kit,
>   Gnu-fdisk and Clamav.<sup>1</sup>

To download click [Here](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/files/URR/iso/ubuntu-rescue-remix-12-04.iso)

See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) for details about how to burn the ISO image to make a bootable CD.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Rescue Remix](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/)</sup>