# How to recover a lost partition on Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, data-recovery, partitioning

I had two Linux OS installed on my machine: Backtrack 5 Gnome and Backtrack5 KDE. I updated the Gnome version and when I rebooted my Grub2 boot manager displayed a `grub rescue>` command line.

I then installed Ubuntu on the same partition with the KDE version to recover my boot-loader. I successfully got the Grub working but unfortunately the kernel for the Gnome OS version doesn't show neither the partition when I set the machine up. Ubuntu is great now but I need some files on the ghost partition.

Please help me retrieve it.

Comment: See this [Deleted Partition Recovery](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery/186203#186203)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you have been actually modifying the partition table and which partitions did you reformat.

I would start with booting from the LiveCD, choosing the rescue mode, and trying to mount any  partitions found manually, then backing up anything of value that you can find there.

Answer (score 0):

*Parts of this answer comes from: [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data/171179#171179)*

By using testdisk you can both recover any lost partitions or undelete selected files/folders.

Take a look at this video in Youtube: [Recover deleted partitions using Testdisk in Ubuntu #11](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EncqYP1ijFg). Additionally I suggest you to take a look on the [Testdisk website](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) in order to get additional instructions on how to use it.

In the past I couldn't fully recover my data because of I was trying to recover using different tools, (including MS Based tools which I don't recommend because of it resulted in the damage of the data itself. So I strongly suggest you to first run the steps mentioned in the video in order to bring back the partition, after which you will be able to undelete/recover any data loss that could happen during data recovery.

Just for information: It took me 2+ weeks to fully recover my data. So please be patience. I am sure we'll find a way to bring your data back.

Good luck!