# Boot section kills data partition

Tags: boot, data-recovery

My Ubuntu installation is partitioned in a drive sda holding Ubuntu and Swap and a drive sdb holding my data. During the installation of a new version of Ubuntu on drive sda I must accedentialy have chosen sdb as the boot partition. Now I don't get access to my data. Also gparted does not see any data on this drive.

Does anybody have an idea how to recover these data?

Comment: I don't know much, but I think you will need another drive to copy sdb onto.  Can see this link for testdisk and/or google for more recent instructions.  Do not use sdb to prevent more lost, remove from system if possible(shutdown and remove usb connection if external drive).  https://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data?rq=1

Comment: If sdb the only way to boot system, use a live ubuntu usb or another computer to find information.  Another link to read.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/253994/lost-data-on-partition?rq=1

Comment: I tnank you for your hints. I have tried the recommended TESTDISK, but found it too complicated for a simple minded user as me. Further surfing led me to RECOVERIT and RAISE DATA RECOVERY FOR EXT2/EXT3/EXT4, two Windows programs and EXTUNDELETE, a linux command line tool. I will try them all and report the results.

Comment: Usually not recommended to use Windows tools/programs to fix Linux and the same in reverse.  Do a lot of reading and research before trying to recover data.  If data is important to you, might be better to get help.  A good local computer person/business can point you in right direction.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with GPARTED. I'm not able to reproduce the way, but accidentally I was able to see status boxes of all drives and I was able to remove the BOOT mark of the sdb drive, holding my data. After removal of that boot mark, my data were accessible as before.

Comment: Finally I was able to reproduce my way trough GPARTED. I simply had to hit the partition with a left click. In the opening window I had to select MANAGE FLAGS and there I had to delete the BOOT marker for my data drive sdb. It took me 4 days to find this simple way for getting access to my data.

Comment: Glad everything worked out well, but I guess this is why everybody says to have good backups.