# Why can't I restore grub after installing Windows?

Tags: grub2, windows-7

Recently I restored windows to default using the acer restore partition and when I restarted, as to be expected, it bypassed grub and went straight into windows.
Now when I try and restore grub it still boots into windows.
The boot repair tool says that it is fixed, but I beg to differ and it gives [this report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1456742/).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Apart from the swap partition, I'm not seeing *any* Linux partitions on that disk.

Answer (score 2):

There's 100GB of unallocated space in the extended partition, before the 4GB swap partition. The Windows Restore erased your Linux partition.

The only thing to do now is trying to recover the lost partition. See: [Deleted Partition Recovery](https://askubuntu.com/q/186193/65926).

Answer (score 1):

1. **Don't write on your disk any more** (including don't use Windows, but work from an Ubuntu live disc).
2. Try to **fix your partition table** via [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)
3. If still not good, try to **recover your lost documents** via TestDisk