# Ubuntu 12.04 live USB just wiped my main install's /home for no apparent reason

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, home-directory

As the title says, I've been trying to reinstall Ubuntu (it died and boot repair won't work), and while I'm checking things on my (very out of date, but it can't be helped as my internet's too slow to download a new version) live USB, making a backup of /home just in case, and trying to make sure it doesn't touch /home on the reinstall... And something happens after I accidentally open the installer and now there's nothing in there, and no methods of recovering data seem to work.

I understand that there may be no way of getting all my stuff back (I did at least get about half my images) but if there's any way to go about it and/or any idea of what happened, that would be great.

(Now if you don't mind, I'm going to go yell at this laptop, as its caused much annoyance for the three years I've had it and its been causing even more over the past four days and I could just scream because of it.)

Comment: well known bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192

Comment: I managed to do something similar, wiping out my /home partition. I recovered it intact using testdisk. Check the existing answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery