# Installing Ubuntu without touching the rest of corrupted drive

Tags: partitioning, uefi, ext4, gpt

I have a notebook with GPT and UEFI. This notebook contains Windows 7. But after some problems **Ubuntu LiveCD destroyed partition table** of this drive and maybe some data.

I urgently need this notebook because I need VT-x for running virtual machines.
I remember that at the end of the drive there was a partition without my data.
I could create a backup of a part of the drive but now I have no place to create a backup of the whole drive.

My Question:

**If I create ext4 and swap partitions at the end of the drive and install Ubuntu, will it damage (change) some of data out of this partitions? I may need to recreate partition table (GPT or MBR).**

Can I run Ubuntu Live CD from BIOS to create GPT partitions?

Edit:
I yesterday have bought new external drive, done a copy of the whole drive with dd and now i mounted my partition image with losetup. So I don't need answer to my question.
You say that similar questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) are answers to my problem:
Problem is similar, but they don't answer my question.
I think that only changes outside ext4 and swap partitions should be MBR (for partition table) and maybe extended partition but it would be very risky.
If nobody will write an answer to my question than I will accept answer from Jason M as helping.
Sorry for grammar errors.

Comment: I wouldn't risk messing with partitions at this stage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, first you should create a image on a external HD of your whole disk using dd, and after that you can try to recover your data from that image. any change of partition map can affect data loss.

hope this helps
Jason

Comment: As I said, now I have no place to to backup of whole drive (500GB).
But I consider buying new external HDD because of this.

Comment: Without a backup of the whole disk, anything else you do is risky. If necessary, buy another disk to hold a backup of the one you want to recover. After that, you should recover your partitions, as described in numerous other questions on this site, like [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery), [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data), and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu).