# Data recovery help

Tags: data-recovery

Recently I installed Ubuntu 14 on my Toshiba laptop overriding windows 8 and ubuntu 10 which was already in it. Only after the installation I realized that this particular option has deleted the earlier partitions and formatted the entire hard drive. I thought 'erase disk' option will format only the os installed drives. Anyhow my last four years work has been lost now :(
Is there any way by which I could possibly retrieve the lost data? (it amounts up to 200 GB). Kindly help me. Is it advisable to consult data recovery firms?

Comment: Also see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'm very sorry to hear that you've lost all your data in this sudden move, I've experienced the same issue with my laptop, and from what I could tell you can use some of the available recovery tools in the software center,

I would recommended system rescue CD you can run it using CD or a USB flash good thing it is support most of the known partition format.

You can also use *Testdisk*. It works within the terminal you can run this command to install it

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

you can also dig into google and make some search for the same problem and you will definitely find the tools you like, I hope you can recover it soon.