# How do I recover my partition table?

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

I booted from a Ubuntu live cd to format but I used *Disks* to view the partitions and accidentally fast formatted the disk without saving the files to my pendrive.

Then I installed `gpart` to view the start and end areas so I can restore the partitions with `parted`.

`sudo gpart /dev/sda` returns:

```
* Warning: more than 4 primary partitions: 8.
Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): primary 
Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): primary 
Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): primary 
Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): primary 
Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): invalid primary 
Partition(Linux swap or Solaris/x86): invalid primary 
Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): invalid primary 
Partition(Linux ext2 filesystem): invalid primary 
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 131(0x83)(Linux ext2 filesystem)
   size: 477mb #s(976896) s(6144-983039)
   chs:  (0/97/34)-(61/48/51)d (0/97/34)-(61/48/51)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 131(0x83)(Linux ext2 filesystem)
   size: 14648mb #s(29999104) s(983040-30982143)
   chs:  (61/48/52)-(1023/254/63)d (61/48/52)-(1928/140/4)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 131(0x83)(Linux ext2 filesystem)
   size: 14648mb #s(29999104) s(30982144-60981247)
   chs:  (1023/254/63)-(1023/254/63)d (1928/140/5)-(3795/231/20)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 131(0x83)(Linux ext2 filesystem)
   size: 19531mb #s(39999488) s(60981248-100980735)
   chs:  (1023/254/63)-(1023/254/63)d (3795/231/21)-(6285/193/52)r
```

Then I used `parted` to rescue with partitions typing the start and end of this 4 partitions, the problem is the last 4 partitions that `gpart` doesn't show, that partitions have all the important data.

Does someone know how to get the start and end of the 4 last partitions or other way to recover them?

Comment: Use `testdisk`.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/286206/167850

Comment: Ouch, actually I should've suggested this instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery

Comment: @David well actually also the solution in the first link provides useful guidance for a similar case, but I realized later that the second one is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. This is what I did:

I installed TestDisk and selected to not save any logs, then the partition type GPT and proceeded to scan for partitions. It found all the partitions.

After that, with `parted /dev/sda > rescue` and adding the start and end numbers of each partition from TestDisk I recovered everything.

Comment: Linux is case sensitive. Be also you case sensitive! "I" is always capital in English.