# Internal HDD cannot give partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk, disk-image

I am having a weird kind of problem. I have a 640gigs internal hdd but it is unusable. It shows up in disks but in weird way.
[Image of disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9I2y.png)

It just gives format partition option and nothing else. The format partition also doesnt do anything. Even format disk option also. The disk is infact old but not at that point that it is unusable. I have an old laptop which has an led indicator which shows the disk usage by blinking accordingly. It blinks during formatting but there is no change in the disks window.

The format disk option works and it gives option to create partition but then it gives [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Qf4.png)

Comment: Did you format and store any data on it before? If not, it probably is a totally unconfigured disk, you can safely create a new partition table (not a partition like EXT4, is a partition table like GPT or MBR) on it. If yes, then consider trying to recover your data first. This answer could be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/875827/how-do-i-recover-my-partition-table

Comment: @Emoji I have nothing in drive currently nor i need backup. I just want it to be partitioned. Yes before it had windows installed in it and now wiped out totally.

Comment: Try using a tool like gparted to create a new partition table on the drive and if you want to use it for Linux only I would recommend giving it an ext4 partition or whatever file-system you prefer using.