# Recovering HDD partition table

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, hard-drive, data-recovery

I found lots of similar topics talking about how to recover deleted partitions I tried several solutions, but nothing worked. In my case, I was installing Archlinux and I used **fdisk** to format part of the HDD and I found out there's a problem with the partitioning after I've written the changes. Some blocks are overlapping! I lost some sensitive data related to my research work and some pictures (since 2010). Is there any way to safely recover my partitions as it was. Note: I've discovered that after installing Archlinux (about 3G) so I expect to lose some data but I'm willing to recover as much as possible. Thanks in advance.

*Note: I use Xubuntu as my main system installed on an SSD drive and the lost files are on my secondary HDD.*

Comment: `photorec` from `testdisk` tools package will recover recoverable files. Please use the search tool on this site, same question have been anserwed many times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleted Partition Recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery)

Comment: I tried both and they didn't work .. Photorec restored some random images that I had and that's all .. any other tools for such an issue .. especially that I still have the overlapping problem with blocks ..

Comment: Did you recover on the disk itself or did you recover from the disk to another disk?

Comment: No, of course, I used my SSD as a storage for the recovery. I refrained to store anything after I discovered what happened.