# I accidentally deleted root using sudo rm *

Tags: sudo, delete, rm, reset

I accidentally used `sudo rm *` while I was in the root directory.
Now, I am not able to open terminal and my computer does not shut down, only a single `_` is flicking on the black screen. How can I solve this/reset my computer?

Comment: You can re-install the system.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186193/deleted-partition-recovery may also be helpful

Comment: Did you run it with the `-r` or `-R` flag, or just plain `rm *`? it makes quite a bit of difference